# react-calendar-timeline buffer disabling horizontal scrolling

Tags: reactjs, react-calendar-timeline

I really like the new buffer prop from 0.28 that allows you to disable/enable horizontal scrolling. However, I can't seem to get it to work when I try using it. Any idea what is wrong with the following code? Thank you for taking a look!

```
                <Timeline
                    groups={groups}
                    items={items}
                    stackItems
                    itemHeightRatio={0.85}
                    canMove={false}
                    canResize={false}
                    buffer={1} // prevent mouse scrolling
                    visibleTimeStart={state.visibleTimeStart}
                    visibleTimeEnd={state.visibleTimeEnd}
                    itemRenderer={itemRenderer}
                    onTimeChange={handleTimeChange}
                    onItemSelect={onItemClick}
                    onItemClick={onItemClick}
                >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buffer` prop is not really to disable/enable the horizontal scroll but to *control the buffer that is rendered on both sides of the calendar*.

The calendar itself is actually a 3x wide scrolling canvas of the screen, which is the default value of buffer = 3. Ideally you should increase this value not decrease it.

[An easy way to disable scroll and zoom](https://github.com/namespace-ee/react-calendar-timeline/issues/369)

To **control/disable the horizontal scroll** use *visibleTimeStart* and *visibleTimeEnd*, and implement `handleOnTimeChange` to only call `updateScrollCanvas` with your *visibleTimeStart* and *visibleTimeEnd*.

```
handleTimeChange = (visibleTimeStart, visibleTimeEnd, updateScrollCanvas) => {
  updateScrollCanvas(moment(this.state.defaultTimeStart).valueOf(), 
  moment(this.state.defaultTimeEnd).valueOf());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, although the current version now uses `onTimeChange`, not `handleOnTimeChange` The syntax is the same though.